# Arrow keys input with graphics.py doesn't work as intended

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python (as of now the only other programming language I'm fluent in is C, so this is all very new to me), and I've decided to make some simple game with it just to get used to it. I'd like it to be an arrow keys controlled game and I'm using the graphics.py library which to my understanding is very beginner friendly.

This is what I came up with:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Game", 800, 500)

def getXInput():
    inputBuffer = win.checkKey()
    inputResult = 0

    if inputBuffer == "Right":
        inputResult = 1
    elif inputBuffer == "Left":
        inputResult = -1

    return inputResult

def getYInput():
    inputBuffer = win.checkKey()
    inputResult = 0

    if inputBuffer == "Down":
        inputResult = 1
    elif inputBuffer == "Up":
        inputResult = -1

    return inputResult  

class player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 250
        self.speed = 3
        self.canMove = True
        self.txt = Text(Point(self.x, self.y), "test")
        self.txt.draw(win)

    def move(self):
        while self.canMove == True:
            xMove = getXInput() * self.speed
            yMove = getYInput() * self.speed

            self.txt.move(xMove, yMove)


def main():
    pl = player()
    pl.move()

    win.close()

main()
```

Player input is managed through the getXInput and getYInput functions, which costantly checks if the arrow keys are pressed and return -1, 0 or 1 accordingly.

Then the result of those functions is costantly multiplied for the player's attribute "speed" and that's how the game is able to move the player character in the correct direction. This kinda works: it works perfectly on the x axis, but it acts weird on y axis, registering inputs only once in a while. Putting the yMove assignment before the xMove one within the move method reverses the problem, making vertical movement perfect and horizontal movement very sloppy. I really can't understand what's causing this, can anybody help?

Comment: If you press a vertical movement key, it's most likely going to be read in `getXInput()` and ignored - there's only a tiny window of opportunity for a keypress to be seen in `getYInput()`.  You need *one* call to `win.checkKey()` per execution of your mainloop, that handles ALL possible keys that might be pressed.  Keep in mind that Python makes it easy to return multiple values from a function - `xMove, yMove = getInput()` perhaps, with things like `return 0, -1` in that function to indicate upward movement.

Comment: This is great, I really didn't know about that, this seems like a pretty powerful feature. I made a single function called getArrowInput which checks for both X and Y inputs and returns a tuple with both values. Then in the player.move method I've assigned the product of self.speed and getArrowInput to a tuple called movement. Finally I called txt.move passing movement[0] and movement[1] as arguments. It worked!

There's just something that I can't get my head around: I can't move the player object diagonally by pressing two arrow keys at once. Here's how I've structured control on input:

Comment: if inputBuffer == "Right":
        inputResultX = 1
    elif inputBuffer == "Left":
        inputResultX = -1
    
    if inputBuffer == "Down":
        inputResultY = 1
    elif inputBuffer == "Up":
        inputResultY = -1

It should check for both X inputs and Y inputs and potentially return something like 1, 1 or 1, -1, etc, but it seems like it never does. I don't necessarly want diagonal movement, but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: `inputBuffer` obviously cannot be equal to both "Right" and "Up" (for example) simultaneously.  `graphics.py`'s input handling is just too simplistic to handle multiple keypresses at the same time.  You would need to move up to something more powerful, like `pygame`.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for your help :)